# Regex 'stalling' when checking certain email addresses

Tags: c#, regex

We have a system that sends transactional emails from external data. As we cannot be sure of the validity of that data, we use a regex to do a fairly basic syntax check and if it fails, record the failure and it will be reviewed.

The regex in question is:

```
^([A-Za-z0-9]([_\.\-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)([_\.\-]?)@([A-Za-z0-9]+)(([\.\-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)\.([A-Za-z]{2,})$
```

Until yesterday, this has worked with no real issues. It has picked up some edge case emails with are dealt with, but for the majority it fits the bill. However, the application started stalling and it  was shown that when checking certain email addresses, the regex would never return, code as follow;

```
var regex = new Regex(regexPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
return regex.IsMatch(email);
```

In order to combat this issue, I have put a timeout into the regex;

```
var regex = new Regex(regexPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
return regex.IsMatch(email);
```

However, the question is why would it simply stall. An example of the emails are;

```
first.laste@domain.co.uk&lpar;M
name@domain.com&lpar;H&rpar;
```

We are sending in excess of 1m records per day and so far today 5 have failed.

Comment: Strange. I don't see any back/forward-references in the regex that could cause timeout/infinite evaluation problems.

Comment: Are you sure that's your regex?  `^(A-Za-z0-9)` would only match the literal string "A-Za-z0-9"

Comment: Your pattern causes catastrophic backtracking

Comment: FYI if you're using the `IgnoreCase` option then you don't need the `a-z` ranges.

Answer (score 3):

Your pattern causes [**catastrophic backtracking**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) with non-matching inputs as your special char pattern (`[_.-]`) is optional inside a quantified group, with the preceding pattern being the same as the pattern that follows the optional special char pattern.

Make the special char pattern obligatory.

Here is a fixed pattern (with some more fixes and removed capturing groups, you may put the capturing parentheses back if you need them (if you analyze matches anywhere later in your code)):

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[_.-][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*[_.-]?@[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[.-][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*\.[A-Za-z]{2,}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4gFz7H/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[A-Za-z0-9]+`  - 1+ letters/digits
- `(?:[_.-][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*` - 0+ repetitions of `_`, `.` or `-` followed with 1+ letters/digits
- `[_.-]?` - an optional `_`, `.` or `-`
- `@` - a `@` char
- `[A-Za-z0-9]+`  - 1+ letters/digits
- `(?:[_.-][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*` - 0+ repetitions of `_`, `.` or `-` followed with 1+ letters/digits
- `\.` - a `.` char
- `[A-Za-z]{2,}` - 2 or more letters
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

This part of the pattern:

```
([A-Za-z0-9]+)(([.-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+))
```

may cause catastrophic backtracking. Those two subpatterns `([A-Za-z0-9]+)` `(([.-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+))` are not mutually exclusive, because of optional part `[.-]?`.

See also:

- https://medium.com/textmaster-engineering/performance-of-regular-expressions-81371f569698#9c11
- http://www.rexegg.com/regex-explosive-quantifiers.html#identifying